# How to know if my networkd configuration was successful?

Tags: networking, systemd

I am writing a small program to reconfigure network interfaces for device, which uses systemd and networkd.
If I modify network configuration files, I need to do `networkctl reload` for changes to take effect. Is there a way to get information whether the network is really reconfigured?
I don't want to have to look into the journal, or manually checking whether interfaces are up (with ifconfig for example).
I thought to check return value of `networkctl reload`, but it is always 0. Even if I enter invalid values for ip address to make it fail.
I also thought to use dbus to do reload, but it always give the same output when reloading. Is there a dbus function I could call to see what configuration is currently in effect?